# Kafka C#: Error occured: Subscribed topic not available: unknown topic or partition

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I am trying to run producer/consumer/ktable code in kafka and I keep getting this error message even though the topics are the same. It was working 2 days ago and I haven't touched my code since but then it suddenly stopped working and gave me this error. When I run the producer code and then the consumer everything works perfectly(meaning that the topic was created properly) However when I run the producer then ktable then consumer it stops working. Any ideas what it could be/solutions for how to get the ktable code to start working again?

This is my ktable code:

```
static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
{ 
    var config = new StreamConfig<StringSerDes, StringSerDes>();
    config.ApplicationId = "test-app";
    config.BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092";
    
    StreamBuilder builder = new StreamBuilder();

    var ktable = builder.Table("topic-read", InMemory.As<string, string>("table-store"));

var kstream = ktable.ToStream();

kstream.To("topicwrite");

    Topology t = builder.Build();
    KafkaStream stream = new KafkaStream(t, config);

    Console.CancelKeyPress += (o, e) => {
        stream.Dispose();
    };

    await stream.StartAsync();
}
```